# save refferer header at 301 redirect from http to http

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, browser, referrer

I have https site on nginx.
If were sent `http` request on this domain, it redirects to `https` version. Exept one url, that send 301 redirect to another `http` domain.

My goal to add in browser's header field `referrer`, when it redirects through `301 redirect` to another domain from `http` part of my site.
I know, that security rules drop referrer header, when browser goes from `https` to `http`. But from `http` to `http` it must work fine, isn't it?

If i just go from some http to another http page through hyperlynk, it save refferer on same browsers, that i used to test 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add referrer from https to http

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check situation into the postman, and read the headers if that works fine for you (HTTP referrers)